# Drupal 8 - custom field plugin & specific taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: plugins, drupal, taxonomy, fieldtype

I'm building a custom compound field in Drupal 8. I'm almost there, but one final bit I'm missing: when I add this new field type to a content type, the taxonomy autocomplete field pulls from every taxonomy vocabulary on the site.

I'm trying to determine how to only pull from a specific "plant_parts" vocabulary. Currently, within my widget code, I've got this:

```
$element['plant_component_measured'] = array(
      '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
      '#target_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
      '#title' => t('Plant part'),
      '#prefix' => '<table><tr><td>',
      '#suffix' => ' ',
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->plant_component_measured) ?
      $items[$delta]->plant_component_measured : NULL, 
  );
```

Comment: actually.. made progress, inserting: '#selection_settings' => array(
            'target_bundles' => array('taxonomy_term', 'plant_part'),
          ),

Answer (score 0):

You can use **STATE** or **CONFIG** API for saving the default value and specify your taxonomy type in `#selection_settings['target_bundles'] = ['plant_part']` as below

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

:
:

if (empty(\Drupal::state()->get('YOUR_MODULE_NAME.plant_component_measured')))
  \Drupal::state()->set('YOUR_MODULE_NAME.plant_component_measured', '');

$entity = Term::load(\Drupal::state()->get('YOUR_MODULE_NAME.plant_component_measured'));
$element['plant_component_measured'] = [
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
  '#title' => $this->t('Plant part'),
  '#description' => $this->t('Plant part'),
  '#prefix' => '<table><tr><td>',
  '#suffix' => ' ',
  '#default_value' => $entity,
  '#selection_handler' => 'default',
  '#selection_settings' => [
    'target_bundles' => [
      'plant_part'
    ],
  ],
];
```

Comment: Just adding #selection_settings' => [  'target_bundles' => 'plant_part'], seemed to help, except for two issues. One, when it renders on the page, it renders the taxonomy id, not the term.  But, I also get errors when I try to edit it. some long error about "entity autocomplete"

Comment: where you actually render this? I think error should be associated with the `#default_value` try to pass the entity as `#default_value` not id.

Comment: Finally getting back to this task... and not having any luck. I used the script above in my widget code, and I still don't see the previously selected term appearing in the field. Everything works still - It just doesn't show what value is in the field.